# Qt and Qwt deploying under ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, qt, qwt, appimage

I wrote a program used to analyze data for a scientific experiment. I used qt creator to write it.
The source code is public under git hub (https://github.com/StefanoPierini/PTU-Analysis-g2)

I would like to create an AppImage of this program in order to make it simple for other Ubuntu users. Furthermore, I tried to deploy in a directory using `cqtdeployer` and then to use `appimage-builder` to create an AppImage.

With some tweaks (like putting the icon image in the right path) I succeed to follow the [tutorial](https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) up to the "Deploying dependencies" step, but when I test to lunch "AppRun" nothing happens.

I would like to know where is my mistake or if there is a simpler method to redistribute a (quite simple) qt application.

Comment: This looks like a promising starting point: https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/Bundling-Qt-apps

Comment: Please open an issue in the appimage-builder repository.

https://github.com/AppImageCrafters/appimage-builder/issues